# How does reject_if: :all_blank for accepts_nested_attributes_for work when working with doubly nested associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have my model setup as below. Everything works fine except blank part records are allowed even if all part and chapter fields are blank.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts, inverse_of: :book
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book, inverse_of: :parts
  has_many :chapters, inverse_of: :part
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :part, inverse_of: :chapters
end
```

Spelunking the code, `:all_blank` gets replaced with `proc { |attributes| attributes.all? { |key, value| key == '_destroy' || value.blank? } }`. So, I use that instead of `:all_blank` and add in some debugging. Looks like what is happening is the part's chapters attribute is responding to `blank?` with `false` because it is an instantiated hash object, even though all it contains is another hash that only contains blank values:

```
chapters_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  '0': !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
    title: ''
    text: ''
```

Is it just not meant to work this way?

I've found a workaround:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts, reject_if: proc { |attributes|
  attributes.all? do |key, value|
    key == '_destroy' || value.blank? ||
        (value.is_a?(Hash) && value.all? { |key2, value2| value2.all? { |key3, value3| key3 == '_destroy' || value3.blank? } })
  end
}
```

But I was hoping I was missing a better way to handle this.

---

**Update 1:** I tried redefining `blank?` for `Hash` but that causes probs.

```
class Hash
  def blank?
    :empty? || all? { |k,v| v.blank? }
  end
end
```

---

**Update 2:** This makes `:all_blank` work as I was expecting it to, but it is ugly and not well-tested.

```
module ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods
  REJECT_ALL_BLANK_PROC = proc { |attributes| attributes.all? { |k, v| k == '_destroy' || v.valueless? } }
end
class Object
  alias_method :valueless?, :blank?
end
class Hash
  def valueless?
    blank? || all? { |k, v| v.valueless? }
  end
end
```

---

**Update 3:** Doh! Update 1 had a typo in it. This version does seem to work.

```
class Hash
  def blank?
    empty? || all? { |k,v| v.blank? }
  end
end
```

Does this have too much potential for unintended consequences to be a viable option? If this is a good option, where in my app should this code live?

Comment: Update #3 does have too many unintended consequences. Dont use it. I suspect the best method is going to be Update #2, but check value.blank? or value is ActionController::Parameters and all its values are either blank or ActionController::Parameters (recursively).

Answer (score 4):

When using `:all_blank` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, it will check each individual attribute to see if it is blank.

```
# From the api documentation
REJECT_ALL_BLANK_PROC = proc do |attributes|
  attributes.all? { |key, value| key == "_destroy" || value.blank? }
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

The attribute of the nested association will be a hash that contains the attributes of the association. The check to see if the attribute is blank will return `false` because the hash is not empty - it contains a key for each attribute of the association. This behavior will cause the `reject_if: :all_blank` to return `false` because of the nested association.

To work around this, you can add your own method to application_record.rb like so:

```
# Add an instance method to application_record.rb / active_record.rb
def all_blank?(attributes)
  attributes.all? do |key, value|
    key == '_destroy' || value.blank? ||
    value.is_a?(Hash) && all_blank?(value)
  end
end

# Then modify your model book.rb to call that method
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts, reject_if: :all_blank?
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I wasn't aware. I have tailored the answer for this particular question.

Comment: Welcome! (BTW, I changed my downvote to an upvote, since it's pretty well-written.)

Answer (score 2):

Methods in previous answers will not work in this case -

```
book = Book.create({ 
  parts_attributes: { 
    name: '',
    chapters_attributes: {[
      { name: '', _destroy: false}, 
      { id: '', name: '', _destroy: false }
    ]} 
  } 
})
```

Here we are providing an array of blank values for chapters with either fields which are blank or _destroy. If you need to reject these values too then you can use this method -

```
 def all_blank?(attributes)
   attributes.all? do |key, value|
     key == '_destroy' || value.blank? ||
     value.is_a?(Hash) && all_blank?(value) ||
     value.is_a?(Array) && value.all? { |val| all_blank?(val) }
   end
 end
```

Here in addition to previous conditions, we have added a line, which checks if all elements in array are blank then reject it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in Rails 4.2.4, so I figured I would share what I've learned.  To promote getting a fix in Rails, see this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19490) and this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23001).

I based my fix on that pull request.  In your case, it would look something like this (just to be clear, the three dots are just to skip over other code):

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts, 
    reject_if: proc { |attributes| deep_blank?(attributes) }
  ...
    def self.deep_blank?(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      next if key == '_destroy'
      any_blank = value.is_a?(Hash) ? deep_blank?(value) : value.blank?
      return false unless any_blank
    end
    true
  end
end
```