# Using :reject_if => :all_blank on double nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have the following models

### Pet

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :owners

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

### Owner

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pets
  has_one :phone_number, :as => :callable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_number
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

### Phone Number

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :callable, polymorphic: true
end
```

### Address

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I have a top level `form_for @pet` with `f.fields_for :owners` nested within and `f.fields_for :phone_number` and `f.fields_for :address` are both nested within the `f.fields_for :owners` block. Which means my `params.require` looks like this.

```
params.require(:pet).permit(:name, :breed, :color, :neutered, :microchip, :flee_control,
        :heartworm_prevention, :date_of_birth, :gender, :species_id, :avatar,
        :owners_attributes => [ :first_name, :last_name, :email,
            :phone_number_attributes => [:number],
            :address_attributes => [:line1, :city, :state, :zip_code] ])
```

My params are all correct and I can create new records and everything works fine. The issue comes when I try to use a `:reject_if => :all_blank` to reject blank owners.

Because there is a second level of nested attributes, `phone_number_attributes` and `address_attributes` are both considered not_blank as they are technically of the type `!ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters`, which allows the object to be built with blank attributes when it shouldn't be.

I've been searching for about 2 hours now and I can't find any mention of this issue. Am I missing something obvious? I've tried adding `:reject_if => :all_blank` on the owner model for the phone number and address with no luck going that route either.

EDIT: I was able to get this to work but there must be a better built-in way to do this.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners, reject_if: proc { |attributes|
    attributes.all? do |key, value|
      if value.is_a? ActionController::Parameters
        value.all? { |nested_key, nested_value| nested_key == '_destroy' || nested_value.blank? }
      else
        key == '_destroy' || value.blank?
      end
    end
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does reject\_if: :all\_blank for accepts\_nested\_attributes\_for work when working with doubly nested associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415205/how-does-reject-if-all-blank-for-accepts-nested-attributes-for-work-when-worki)

Answer (score 3):

I have not seen a built in way to accomplish what you are trying to do, but a work around that I have used is to extend the example found in the api documentation like so:

```
# Add an instance method to application_record.rb / active_record.rb
def all_blank?(attributes)
  attributes.all? { |key, value| key == '_destroy' || value.blank? || (all_blank?(value) if value.is_a?(Hash)) }
end

# Then modify your model pet.rb to call that method
accepts_nested_attributes_for : owners, reject_if: :all_blank?
```

The original example from the api

```
REJECT_ALL_BLANK_PROC = proc { |attributes| attributes.all? { |key, value| key == "_destroy" || value.blank? } }
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html