# Cannot validate empty nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a nested form for creating members inside an enrollment

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :atendees, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :atendees, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and validations on Member model.

If I submit the enrollment form with all blank member fields, the enrollment saves successfully with an empty members array.

If I input any member field and submit it, member model validations take action.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I also tried with checking only one column:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :atendees, , reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['first_name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: Can you mention the ruby version you are using? if latest you can try this: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :atendees, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true`

Comment: @Meer that's how I originally tried.

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415205...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415205/how-does-reject-if-all-blank-for-accepts-nested-attributes-for-work-when-worki) and this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963769...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963769/accepts-nested-attributes-for-ignore-blank-values). Let me know if this helps

Comment: @Meer unfortunately nope.. Still can submit the enrollment with blank member fields. Tried solutions from both posts.

Comment: please update your question to include both the associated models and also mention ruby and rails versions you are on. will check it then.

Comment: ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.4. I have an sti on enrollment with Single and Team inheriting from Enrollment. Enrollment has many members. I'll edit my question in a bit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems like the expected behaviour. [reject_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) should 'silently' ignore any fields that fail to meet the condition. If you removed reject_if clause then the usual model validation should occur for member instances.

If not, then you can use [validates_associated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated) in the Enrollment model

```
validates_associated :atendees
```

Comment: but would this `validates_associated :atendees` throw an exception with blank associated record?

Comment: It would return false because all validates_associated does is call valid? method (returning a boolean) which runs validations on each of the associated record attributes. If it returns false then it will prevent the associated record from saving and rollback the entire transaction but it shouldn't throw an exception.